# How to join two count queries together in one?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables that I need to get a count of entries per person summed between the two tables.

I need to join the following queries together in one grouped by the name.

```
select count(entryid) as table1count, reqname1 from table1
```

And the second query:

```
select count(comid) as table2count, reqname2 from table2
```

How would I put these together so that I ended up with output like this:

```
jsmith 236
jsnow 13
etc.
```

Sometimes the same reqname will be in both tables, but it could only be in one or the other. So I want to show all reqnames between the two tables and their counts summed between the two tables.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sub query that performs a `union all`, and then group and count:

```
select name, count(id) 
from (
        select reqname1 as name, entryid as id from table1
        union all
        select reqname2, comid from table2
     ) as combined
group by name
```

Comment: One more thing. How would I work in some date range checking. Say I wanted to get the same results when either date1 is between 8/21/2017 and 8/28/2017 or date2 is between 8/21/2017 and 8/28/2017?

Comment: That is a completely different question: after selecting those date fields, add `where date1 between #2017-08-21# and #2017-08-28# or date2 between #2017-08-21# and #2017-08-28#`. If you cannot make that work, please ask a new question. The comments section is not intended for new questions. ;-)

Comment: Thanks generating a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
select count(entryid) as table1count, reqname1 from table1
UNION ALL
select count(comid) as table2count, reqname2 from table2
```

Comment: This will produce duplicate names when they occur in both tables.